# I know there is difference between "grow" and "grow up", but it is hard for me to tell when it comes to an example

Tags: word-usage, phrases

It is said in some dictionaries that "grow" means to increase in amount, size, number, or strength, while "grow up" means one changes from being a child into being an adult or to stop behaving in a silly or childish way.

I want to write a sentence that means if one does something he has never done before, he will become mature. But I don't know which is correct after I compare "grow" and "grow up" in the following sentences.

1. To do things you have never done before is called growing.
2. To do things you have never done before is called growing up.

Answer (score 4):

Both terms are perfectly acceptable in the cited context. Broadly speaking they mean about the same thing - it's just that they have significantly different connotations.

Native speakers will understand this *specific* use of ***growing*** as a metaphorical reference to ***developing, improving*** (intellectually and/or emotionally, not literally as in increased physical stature). Even a 70-year-old could say something like...

> *I still like to learn new things - [when you stop learning, you stop growing.](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22stop%20learning%20you%20stop%20growing%22)*

In the above context it would be *extremely* unusual (bordering on "nonsensical") to use ***growing up***, with all its connotations of the specific difference between childish and adult behaviour / attitudes.

Note that ***to grow up*** in this context is similar to ***to end up, to finish up, to break up*** - that added preposition imparts a note of "completeness, finality". The implication being that there are only two possible states for a human being - ***childish*** (but "developing") and ***grown-up*** (a static end state).

---

TL;DR: If you want to talk about how people (young and old alike) can develop / improve their emotional and cognitive skills by continually exposing themselves to new experiences and information, use ***growing***.

If you just want to focus on (one of) the defining characteristics of ***adolescence*** (the transition from child to adult), use ***growing up***.

Answer (score 2):

Literally, **to grow** is to become bigger, and to **grow up** is to grow towards *maturity* or to attain maturity.

A river may **grow** after a heavy rain, but a river cannot **grow up**.

Only that which can reach maturity can **grow up**.

That which can reach maturity can **grow** and it can also **grow up**.

Figuratively, **to grow** means to develop mentally and emotionally.

So, when we use **grow** of people, it can mean "to become physically larger" (literal) or "to become emotionally and mentally more developed" (figurative).

Figuratively, **to grow up** means to become an adult, or to reach adulthood, emotionally, in our mental outlook.

Comment: +1 for "Figuratively, to grow means to develop mentally and emotionally." That's the key to why the OP's first option may be the more appropriate one.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the sentence to mean, that the person matures, then the second choice is better.

You already gave the reason for it in your question by saying, that "growing up" means to mature.

Comment: To be honest, I inclined to choose "grow up", but I was not sure of it. Thank you.